# Auto generate Primary Key if not present in MySQL INSERT Query

Tags: mysql

I created a table in MySql

```
CREATE TABLE newuser(id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,sname VARCHAR(20));
```

When I INSERT record it works fine

```
INSERT INTO newuser VALUE('abc123','monika');
```

But sometimes I don't want to supply id in the INSERT query and sometimes I want to supply. In case I don't supply id MySql automatically generate one.

What can I do to get both below query works?

```
INSERT INTO newuser VALUE('abc123','monika');
INSERT INTO newuser VALUE('nikita');
```

Comment: 'MySql should automatically generate one' - you have to code for this yourself. AND unless you are inserting to all columns you have to specify which columns you are inserting to.

Comment: What should i code

Comment: How should I know you haven't stated how you arrive at your primary key.

Comment: Any key which is not already present in the table

Comment: You mean a unique identifier whose only attribute is it's uniqueness?

Comment: Yes any unique id alphanumeric

Comment: Then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid perhaps

Comment: Sorry, sir, I don't understood anything but I want is some random key should be inserted since it is primary key it can not be duplicate So some number should be generated which is not already in table

Comment: `UUID()` is a unique identifier, However you can use `MD5(sname)` too. But need extend your id size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I don't understood ANYTHING' - very new then.

Firstly second insert statement is invalid please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html -
'If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list, SELECT statement, or TABLE statement.'

Secondly uuid is a function in which 'A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

You can easily select uuid() to see what it produces.
You will need to increase the id size
If you wish to use it in an insert

```
insert into users values (uuid(),<sname>);
```